# Can you use generic controllers AND generic services for a backend CRUD API?

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-web-api, crud

I'm working on a backend project, building a RESTful API for a number of entities.  Right now, the task is to build out your basic CRUD abilities for each one of the current entities in the design.  Later on, I'll get more sophisticated, but for now all I need to do is create API endpoints that let you get, create, update or delete from the repository for each entity.

Since I want to apply the same types of operations to a variety of different entity types, I thought to use a generic controller class.  This let me avoid having to write in the boilerplate (method names, HTTP verbs specified for each, etc.) for each entity's controller.  That looks something like this:

```
public class EntityCRUDController<TService, TDetail, TSummary> : ApiController
    where TService: IEntityCRUDService<TDetail, TSummary>
{
    protected readonly TService _service;

    public EntityCRUDController(TService service)
    {
        _service = service;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [Route("")]
    public async Task<TSummary> GetAll()
    {
        return await _service.GetAll();
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [Route("{entityId}")]
    public async Task<TDetail> GetSpecific(Guid entityId)
    {
        return await _service.GetSpecific(entityId);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [Route("")]
    public IHttpActionResult Create([FromBody]TDetail entityDetail)
    {
        _service.Create(entityDetail);
        return Ok();
    }

    [HttpPut]
    [Route("{entityId}")]
    public IHttpActionResult Update(Guid entityId, [FromBody]TDetail entityDetail)
    {
        _service.Update(entityDetail);
        return Ok();
    }

    [HttpDelete]
    [Route("{entityId}")]
    public IHttpActionResult Delete(Guid entityId)
    {
        _service.Delete(entityId);
        return Ok();
    }
}
```

So that actually works quite well.  It's extensible too, so I can still add any additional endpoints beyond the CRUD boilerplate that I need.  But then I thought, if I can make the controllers generic, why not make the services generic too?

Each controller is injected with a service, which lets the controller perform these CRUD operations. Each service, in turn, is injected with a repository which knows how to actually interact with the infrastructure layer.

The problem comes with trying to implement the generic service object inside the generic service class.  I'm trying to use an abstract class to have each service object inherit from.  That abstract class will contain the main CRUD methods, since those are basically the same operation for each entity.

I've tried a variety of ways of implementing this but haven't been able to make it work.  Every time I do I just go around in circles and confuse myself.  Either I can't get it to compile, or it does compile and I can't get the generic service to inject correctly into the controller.

So how would you do it if you wanted to reuse as much code as possible? I want to have reusable generic methods for the standard CRUD operations, but then the option to add additional methods unique to each entity type.  I can make it work just fine with only generic controllers, but then I'm consigned to duplicating the main CRUD code inside each service.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are using EF, it is an easy task by using repository pattern. A generic class named Repository which has methods for create, read, update and delete. You can optionally introduce an interface to a better dependency injection:

Public interface IRepository
{
Public void Add(T entity);
//....
}

Public class Repository: IRepository
{
Public Repository(/* inject DI here */)
{}

Public void Add(T entity)
{ 
_dbSet.Add(entity);
}
//.....
}

Comment: I'm already using a generic repository and interface for each one of the entities. So, that is where the heart of the code lies.  But I was hoping to avoid having the boilerplate of a controller that calls a method on a service, that calls a method on a repository, which then accesses the infrastructure layer.  Those first two steps are just dumb calls into the next architectural layer, so I want to make them generic.

Comment: You may like OData controllers which include a complete set of database operations by default.